# CSS positioning multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I need to display a summary report using [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) with 4 pie graphs and 1 bar graph.

This is a screenshot of the specs:

[image: report summary]

All of the examples on Highcharts only show a single graph, and I am not sure how to get the controls small enough to fit on the top of the page or how to show all of them at one time.

In their [pie example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown), they have a single `<div>` tag called "container":

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

The javascript populates it with their call:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
```

Using the question below:

[Show/Update Separate Bar graphs with Drilldown Pie chart of Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103904)

It looks like I need to create multiple  containers for each:

- pieSubstation,
- pieFeeder,
- pieCycle,
- pieRate, and
- barCount.

```
<div id="pieSubstation"></div>
<div id="pieFeeder"></div>
<div id="pieCycle"></div>
<div id="pieRate"></div>
<div id="barCount"></div>
```

When I simply put those on the page, they show up with each below the other, and they are all large.

I am not good at [positioning HTML using CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). Once I start modifying the CSS using absolute, relative, or fixed, my webpage becomes unpredictable.

I need to position my  graphs so that

1. they are all at the top of the form,
2. the pie charts are all in quarters on the left half, and
3. the bar graph is on the right half.

How would CSS do this? Or is there another way?

**UPDATE:**

I am using the information provided in the 2 answers below, but the pie charts still only display one on top of the other, like shown below:

[image: screenshot]

I am still trying to get the data formatted to display in 5 simultaneous controls, so the graphs are all empty ...for now!

However, what you see above uses the exact bootstrap code provided by [Tch in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946134/153923) and it looked the same using the code provided by [terrymorse in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946398/153923).

Is there some reason why the Highchart graphs would not display like the specs call for?

**UPDATE 2:**

I don't think the javascript below will help, because the data is returned from the SQL Server stored procedure. It returns 16,000 records in our development environment that spans 2 different databases, but perhaps it will give someone an idea of how I am populating the data for the Highchart grids.

```js
function onDataBound(e) {
    var emptySpan = $('.empty-span');
    emptySpan.text('');
    $("#UP").toggle(false);
    var tab = $('#tabstrip > ul > li.k-item.k-state-default.k-tab-on-top.k-state-active > span.k-link');
    if (tab !== null) {
        var tabText = tab.text();
        var hashId = '#grid';
        if (tabText == 'Electric') {
            hashId = '#gridElectric';
        } else if (tabText == 'Gas') {
            hashId = '#gridGas';
        } else if (tabText == 'Water') {
            hashId = '#gridWater';
        }
        var grid = $(hashId).data('kendoGrid');
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
            grid.autoFitColumn(i);
        }
        var lblBarTo010 = '0 to 10';
        var lblBarTo100 = '10 to 100';
        var lblBarTo365 = '100 to 365';
        var lblBarOver1 = 'More than 365';
        var pie1 = [];
        var pie2 = [];
        var pie3 = [];
        var pie4 = [];
        var bar1 = {
            lblBarTo010: 0,
            lblBarTo100: 0,
            lblBarTo365: 0,
            lblBarOver1: 0
        };

        var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
        $.each(grid.items(), function (index, item) {
            var uid = $(item).data('uid');
            var row = dataSource.getByUid(uid);
            var service = row.ServiceType;
            if (service == 'Electric') {
                pie1.push(row);
                pie2.push(row);
            }
            pie3.push(row);
            pie4.push(row);
            var days = row.Days;
            if (days < 10) {
                var increment = bar1[lblBarTo010] + 1
                bar1[lblBarTo010] = increment;
            } else if (days < 100) {
                var increment = bar1[lblBarTo100] + 1
                bar1[lblBarTo100] = increment;
            } else if (days < 100) {
                var increment = bar1[lblBarTo365] + 1
                bar1[lblBarTo365] = increment;
            } else {
                var increment = bar1[lblBarOver1] + 1
                bar1[lblBarOver1] = increment;
            }
        });
        var charts = { // chart id, title, chart type, data[], xAxis, yAxis
            1: ['piefigcontainer1', 'Meter Count per Substation (Top 10)', 'pie', pie1 ],
            2: ['piefigcontainer2', 'Meter Count per Feeder (Top 10)', 'pie', pie2 ],
            3: ['piefigcontainer3', 'Meter Count per Cycle (Top 10)', 'pie', pie3 ],
            4: ['piefigcontainer4', 'Meter Count per Rate (Top 10)', 'pie', pie4 ],
            5: ['barfigcontainer1', 'Meter Count per Gap Tier (in Days)', 'bar', bar1 ]
        };
        $.each(charts, function (key, value) {
            var plotOptions = [];
            var series = [];
            console.log('creating ' + value[2] + ' graph... ');
            if (value[2] == 'pie') {
                plotOptions = {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}%</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                if (key < 3) {
                    series = { // donut: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_pie_donut.htm
                        name: value[1],
                        data: value[3],
                        size: '60%',
                        dataLabels: {

                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    series = { // basic pie: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_pie_basic.htm
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Meter Count',
                        data: value[3],
                    };
                }
            } else { // basic bar: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_bar_basic.htm
                plotOptions = {
                    bar: {
                        dataLabels: { enabled: true, }
                    },
                };
                series = [
                    {
                        name: lblBarTo010,
                        data: bar1[lblBarTo010]
                    },
                    {
                        name: lblBarTo100,
                        data: bar1[lblBarTo100]
                    },
                    {
                        name: lblBarTo365,
                        data: bar1[lblBarTo365]
                    },
                    {
                        name: lblBarOver1,
                        data: bar1[lblBarOver1]
                    },
                ];
            }
            Highcharts.chart(value[0], {
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: value[2]
                },
                credits: { text: '' },
                title: { text: value[1] },
                plotOptions: plotOptions,
                series: series,
           });
        });
    }
};
```

**Solved!**

Tch's code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div id="piefigcontainer1" class="mb-25 h-200"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div id="piefigcontainer2" class="h-200"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div id="piefigcontainer3" class="h-200"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div id="piefigcontainer4" class="h-200"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="barfigcontainer1" class="h-425"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: result]

Now I just have to figure out how to size the text and fill the data.

Comment: Unclear what's preventing the layout formatting. Can you add to your question the HTML snippet used to produce that screenshot?

Comment: @terrymorse, I added Update2 with javascript

Comment: The JavaScript does not show the HTML markup. Please post the actual HTML that exists on the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a very simple example. but I suggest you dive into [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) taht has a very nice grid system stylesheet, and other useful css/js stuff

```
<style>
html,body {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
.wh-50 {
    width:50%;
   height:50%;
    float: left;
}
.wh-100 {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="wh-50">
        <div  id="pieSubstation" class="wh-50"></div>
        <div id="pieFeeder" class="wh-50"></div>
        <div id="pieCycle" class="wh-50"></div>
        <div id="pieRate" class="wh-50"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wh-50">
        <div id="barCount" class="wh-100"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

bootstrap4 version should look like this, you can ommit the height class if the charts have minimum heights

```
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.h-200 {
    width:100%;
    min-height:200px;
}
.mb-25 {
margin-bottom:25px;
}
.h-425 {
    min-height:425px;
}
</style>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div  id="pieSubstation" class="mb-25 h-200"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div id="pieFeeder" class="h-200"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div id="pieCycle" class="h-200"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div id="pieRate"  class="h-200"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div id="barCount"  class="h-425"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is what I see if I put background color in every div
[image]

Comment: Cool. We actually use some bootstrap in this code. I am a Windows Forms developer, so I could not tell you what it's for. Is there an alternate way to do this using bootstrap? Don't delete this answer, but you can edit and add another method.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what is going on. I updated the question by posting how the results look - not what I'm after. I might have to force it using an HTML table.

Comment: first of all, do you include the bootstrap4 css/js files in your html? second does your javascript initiate the charts in the correct divs? do your charts have actual data to present? could you post the page you are working on, on a live link or on your post using code?

Comment: 1) Looking in our company's project, they are using **Bootstrap v3.3.7**. Will that be a problem? Upgrading to bootstrap4, by corporate policy, would mean testing every page in the Enterprise solution, because they all use the same code.

Comment: change every `col-sm` to `col-sm-6` and be sure no other css is messing things up, that is why I asked for you full code

Comment: Eureka! That did it. Thank you! I didn't think it was possible.

Answer (score 2):

The requried layout is 4 small boxes on the left, and one large box on the right.

This is the Bootstrap structure needed to produce that layout:

```sh
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| row                                                                   |
| +-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+ |
| | col-6                             | col-6                         | |
| | +-------------------------------+ |                               | |
| | | row                           | |                               | |
| | | +-------------+-------------+ | |                               | |
| | | | col-6       | col-6       | | |                               | |
| | | +-------------+-------------+ | |                               | |
| | | +-------------+-------------+ | |                               | |
| | | | col-6       | col-6       | | |                               | |
| | | +-------------+-------------+ | |                               | |
| +-----------------------------------+-------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And here is that structure implemented:

```css
/* some styling just to show the layout */
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-6 {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px dashed #a0a0a0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<body class="p-4">

<h5>Bootstrap layout</h5>

    <!-- one large row -->
    <div class="row">
    
      <!-- containing two large columns of equal width -->
      <div class="col-6">

        <!-- left large column has two rows containing two columns
             each -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">small graph</div>
          <div class="col-6">small graph</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">small graph</div>
          <div class="col-6">small graph</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- right large column to contain the big graph -->
      <div class="col-6">
        Big Graph
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I've seen that type of markup in our HTML. I guess that's what bootstrap is. I'm trying to see how to apply that to the `<figure>` tag. For some reason, it isn't acting like your `<div>` tags - or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: figure is just a tag as div, but with the small difference that some browsers have predefined style different for each tag

Comment: @jp2code Bootstrap styles `<figure>` slightly differently than `<div>`. The only difference is that Bootstrap adds a margin of `1rem` at the bottom of a `<figure>`. That might mess up the row and column formatting. To be on the safe side, use `<div class="col-6"><figure>...</figure></div>`

Comment: For some reason it isn't working. I updated the question using a screenshot of the results. I don't understand why it isn't working. Should I force it with an HTML table?